# setShowConnectingPopup is not working in onCreate() in Application class

Tags: android, google-play-services

As the title saying , here's my code of application class :

```
public class GlobalAccess extends Application implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks , GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .addApi(Drive.API).addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
            .build();

    client.connect();

    Games.GamesOptions.builder().setShowConnectingPopup(true).build();
}
```

This problem is so weird that I don't know how to solve it so don't mind me if I'm missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You cannot display an application window/dialog through a Context
>   that is not an Activity or Service.
>    If you really want to show you diallog from an application, you will have to pass an Activity context to it.

Comment: you have to call this from class which extends Activity not Application.

Comment: do you mean the context of client `GoogleApiClient.Builder` or context of application class ?

Comment: where you want some UI widgets you need activity context .... in your case you have to use `GoogleApiClient` connection in your activity `onCreate();`

Comment: IT WORKED , THANKS :D